# How to limit the access to a Controller or a folder in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I use Asp.Net MVC 3, C# together with ApplicationServices Membership (the standard way suing MS Sql 2008 db).

My folder structure is

```
CONTROLLERS
-- PageAController.cs
-- ADMIN
   -- PageBController.cs
```

I have a Users some with Role "AdminRole", some with no rules associated (anonymouse).

I would like **DENY** access to the specific Controller and show a LOGIN page for `PageAController.cs` and to all Controllers within folder `ADMIN` for User that HAVE NOT the "AdminRole" associated.

- What it the way to go?
- Do I need setup Web.Config... how?

Comment: Just to make it clear: you want to deny the access to all actions in the `PageAController` to all users that have the `AdminRole`? I didn't understand your second requirement. You seem to be talking about some files. What files? In ASP.NET MVC there are controllers and actions and views. It's the controller actions responsibility to control access.

Comment: My apologies my question was not clear, I need to DENY to all users that have NOT the AdminRole

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope this helps

[Use AuthorizeAttribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

> You cannot use routing or web.config files to secure your MVC
>   application. The only supported way to secure your MVC application is
>   to apply the [Authorize] attribute to each controller and action
>   method (except for the login/register methods). Making security
>   decisions based on the current area is a Very Bad Thing and will open
>   your application to vulnerabilities

```
[Authorize(Roles="AdminRole")]
public class PageAController
{

}

[Authorize(Roles="AdminRole,AnotherRole")]
public class PageBController
{

}
```

Comment: What about securing a method that happens to exist in the controller, but should not be called by MVC.  Should it just be marked private?  Would protected work as well?