# Add Data from Another Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add data from one controller to another, what should I make?
I have one controller e.g Name and another addName with entity data model view
 (index,create,delete,details) and AddName with index.
I want to add data from addName in Name Controller's model. Please help me.

Comment: shouldn't addName just be an action in your Name controller? addName sounds effectively like a Create action.

Comment: I want use it for admin panel and after authentication add data, can you advise me anything?

Comment: Create role admin. Then add [Authorize(Role="admin")]. See example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723294/how-to-limit-the-access-to-a-controller-or-a-folder-in-mvc You would place this on top of your AddName action in your Name controller. This would stop regular users from having access to that particular action.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Controllers, Actions, and Action Results](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/actions.html) article will shed some light on your issues. Note the tip which states

> “The Controller is a UI level abstraction…In well-factored apps it
>   will not directly include data access or business logic, but instead
>   will delegate to services handling these responsibilities”

.
The [Overview of ASP.NET Core MVC](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/overview.html) article explains the MVC pattern. This article discusses the ***responsibilities of the Model, View, and Controller***. In addition to explaining the benefits of adhering to the MVC pattern, there are links to additional articles regarding ***separation of concerns*** and the ***Single Responsibility Principal***.